# Simple WiX web installer

Tags: wix

I just got the WiX designer yesterday and created a setup project to install a web site. I ran through the steps in the help PDF for a simple web site install and when running the setup, I get the following error: 
    *CustomAction WEBCA_SetTARGETSITE returned actual error code 1603*

To be sure, I created a new solution, created a new ASP.net MVC website, added a new WiX setup project and followed the instructions again. Same error again. Any ideas what's wrong with my project?

Thanks.

Comment: To be clear, I got the Visual Studio add-in from https://www.add-in-express.com for the WiX Designer.

Answer (score -1):

Seems that WiX 3 does not support IIS 7+ yet.  So if you don't have IIS 6 compatibility installed, the WiX install just fails with the cryptic error above.  From what I can tell WiX 4 will have support for IIS 7+, but no word on when that will be released.  I did not find any simple solutions to getting it to work without compatibility enabled.